# Ikev2 Strongswan vpn: UFW doesnt route internet traffic

Tags: vpn, firewall, ufw

I [installed a strongswan ikev2 vpn](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-ikev2-vpn-server-with-strongswan-on-ubuntu-18-04-2) many times on ubunut without problems. But now on a fresh installed ubuntu server I cant get it to run.
Connect to the vpn does work but I cant get a internet connection. I still can connect to the server while connected to the vpn so I guess the ufw firewall doesnt route my connection to the internet.

I tried to allow everything on the ufw firewall with "ufw default allow".

In the ufw.log it still says that connection from the intenet to my ip (server) are still blocked, idk if this is the reason that this doesnt work.

Here are my ufw configs:

/etc/ufw/before.rules:

```
#
# rules.before
#
# Rules that should be run before the ufw command line added rules. Custom
# rules should be added to one of these chains:
#   ufw-before-input
#   ufw-before-output
#   ufw-before-forward
#

*nat
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.0/24 -o enp2s0 -m policy --pol ipsec --dir out -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.0/24 -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT

*mangle
-A FORWARD --match policy --pol ipsec --dir in -s 10.10.10.0/24 -o enp2s0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -m tcpmss --mss 1361:1536 -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1360
COMMIT

# Don't delete these required lines, otherwise there will be errors
*filter
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-not-local - [0:0]
# End required lines

-A ufw-before-forward --match policy --pol ipsec --dir in --proto esp -s 10.10.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward --match policy --pol ipsec --dir out --proto esp -d 10.10.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT

# allow all on loopback
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT

# quickly process packets for which we already have a connection
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# drop INVALID packets (logs these in loglevel medium and higher)
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP

# ok icmp codes for INPUT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

# ok icmp code for FORWARD
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

# allow dhcp client to work
-A ufw-before-input -p udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT

#
# ufw-not-local
#
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local

# if LOCAL, RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN

# if MULTICAST, RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN

# if BROADCAST, RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN

# all other non-local packets are dropped
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP

# allow MULTICAST mDNS for service discovery (be sure the MULTICAST line above
# is uncommented)
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -d 224.0.0.251 --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT

# allow MULTICAST UPnP for service discovery (be sure the MULTICAST line above
# is uncommented)
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -d 239.255.255.250 --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT

# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these rules won't be processed
COMMIT
```

/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf:

```
#
# Configuration file for setting network variables. Please note these settings
# override /etc/sysctl.conf and /etc/sysctl.d. If you prefer to use
# /etc/sysctl.conf, please adjust IPT_SYSCTL in /etc/default/ufw. See
# Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt in the kernel source code for more
# information.
#

# Uncomment this to allow this host to route packets between interfaces
#net/ipv4/ip_forward=1
#net/ipv6/conf/default/forwarding=1
#net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding=1

# Disable ICMP redirects. ICMP redirects are rarely used but can be used in
# MITM (man-in-the-middle) attacks. Disabling ICMP may disrupt legitimate
# traffic to those sites.
net/ipv4/conf/default/accept_redirects=0
net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_redirects=0
net/ipv6/conf/default/accept_redirects=0

# Ignore bogus ICMP errors
net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts=1
net/ipv4/icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses=1
net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all=0

# Don't log Martian Packets (impossible addresses)
# packets
net/ipv4/conf/all/log_martians=0
net/ipv4/conf/default/log_martians=0

#net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout=30
#net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl=1800

# Uncomment this to turn off ipv6 autoconfiguration
#net/ipv6/conf/default/autoconf=1
#net/ipv6/conf/all/autoconf=1

# Uncomment this to enable ipv6 privacy addressing
#net/ipv6/conf/default/use_tempaddr=2
#net/ipv6/conf/all/use_tempaddr=2

net/ipv4/ip_forward=1
net/ipv4/conf/all/accept_redirects=0
net/ipv4/conf/all/send_redirects=0
net/ipv4/ip_no_pmtu_disc=1
```

ufw status:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
20                         ALLOW       Anywhere
25565                      ALLOW       Anywhere
500,4500/udp               ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
20 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
25565 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
500,4500/udp (v6)          ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```